# Cannot ssh into Google-Engine, connecting in a loop

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I am unable to connect through SSH to my GCE instance. I was connecting without any problem, the only think I changes was my user name through top right corner of the browser then selected `Change Linux Username`.

When I try to ssh into my google engine via browser, I keep having following message in a endless loop:

[image]

When I try to ssh via cloud shell I also get following error message, (*serial console output*):

```
Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

**[Q]** Is there any way to fix this problem? Since I have no access to the engine now, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Would you please try delete your Metadata ssh key from your dashboard related to the old user and the new user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you could always get back access through serial console then from there you could internally y troubleshoot user/ssh issue.

1) `$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME] --metadata=serial-port-enable=1`

You can then connect to the instance through the serial port
NOTE:The root password have must been already set in order to use the serial port

2)

```
$ gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

If you never set the root password you could set it by adding a startup-script to your instance that will set a password as root by running the below command :
NOTE: the instance must be rebooted in order to run the startup script.

3) `$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata [instance name] --metadata startup-script='echo "root:YourPasswdHere" | chpasswd'`

Reboot the instance run the command on the step "2)" authenticate your self as root with the password that you set on the startup script in the step "3)" .

Comment: I have deleted my old user's ssh key on the metadata but didn't help. Should I run those gcloud code lines on the google shell? I never set the root password my only left option is case-3 I guess. @Alessio

Comment: I managed to login via google shell! But still I cannot login via ssh browser, what might be the reason for that? Is there any way to fix it? @Alessio

Comment: When you click on ssh button on your Dashboard a tiny ssh client "somewhere" on the cloud will connect to the instance and will redirect the output to your browser. So it isn't your local machine that will establish an ssh connection to your instance. Having said that let me remember that the ssh client own a  private and public ssh key.

Comment: My Bad,I missed the second part:
You switched from user1 to user2 therefore a new home directory was created for user2.
What I'm epecting is that the new user user2 is not retrieving the public key from the metadata.
The VM has a google daemon running that continuously check for metadata changes.
In order to check if this is your case please run the below command

Comment: Please see output of pastebin.com/raw/KnRrTUV1 from here https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/a77cfa3c795a41a3048a24d2189094d3 – @Alessio

Comment: Please see output of pastebin.com/raw/KnRrTUV1 from here https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/a77cfa3c795a41a3048a24d2189094d3  //I am still having the same error and could not able to fix it. – @Alessio

Comment: Ok, according to your output there is not ssh key for user alper1 alper2.

Comment: Let's add it manually. Run the following command https://paste.googleplex.com/5730797701038080 . If this doesn't work please run again the previous ssh debug command to see if actually a new key were added

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, It took me several days to figure out what was happening in my case.

To find out, I created a new instance from scratch and started making all modifications I've done to those that eventually couldn't connect to, one by one, exiting the ssh connection and re entering so as to test it.

I've tried it a couple of times, in both cases, the connection was impossible after uninstalling python (I only needed 3.7 version so I was uninstalling all others and installing that one I needed).

My command for uninstalling it was
sudo apt purge python2.7-minimal
and
sudo apt purge python3.5-minimal

I don't know if it was specifically because of deleting python, or because of using purge (in which case this problem might reproduce if using purge with another program).
I don't even know why would this affect ssh connection.

Could it be that google cloud is somehow using destination python for the ssh web?

In any case, if you are experiencing this problem try to avoid uninstalling anything from the base VM.